# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not TextIOWrapper when using open() to open a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to open a file, modify it, and then save it. I have the open part working but I am having problems with line 50. The error is 'TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not TextIOWrapper'

```
def save_file():
    global open_status_name
    text_file = open_status_name
    if open_status_name:
        text_file = open(open_status_name, 'w') # error: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not TextIOWrapper
        text_file.write(text.get(1.0, END))
        text_file.close()
        status_bar.config(text=f'Saved: {open_status_name}        ')
    else:
        save_as()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `.name` attribute to access the file :

```
text_file=open(open_status_name.name, 'w')
```

Comment: Oh my god. I cannot explain how happy I was when I saw that this worked. Thank you soooo much. You are a real GOD and life saver :)

Comment: You don't need to include `global open_status_name` unless you intend to change the value.